# Select con WHERE IN (User-Defined Table Types)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a query with a string array that is not a user entered array, I have defined the following type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[searchData] AS TABLE([searchInput] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
```

In a stored procedure I fill the `@tempTable` variable of table type `[searchData]` with a WHILE, but when

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column1Tabla2 
FROM Tabla1 INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON DT_Tabla1.Column2 = Tabla2.Column1Tabla2 
WHERE Column1 IN (select * from @tempTable)

select * from @tempTable --Devuelve todos los valores que hay en la tabla
```

only return the last value of [searchData].

Comment: can you post everything in English and remove Spanish words.

Comment: Can you also post the while loop that populates the table variable?

Comment: Why are you using a WHILE loop? Why aren't you using a table-valued parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not really make sense, and I don't believe it will compile:

```
WHERE Column1 IN (select * from @tempTable)
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
WHERE Column1 IN (select SearchInput from @tempTable)
```

Comment: Yes, [`c IN (SELECT * FROM t)` does compile](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8022) when `t` has got a single column.

Comment: @AndriyM weird, I still don't know why you would ever want to write it that way though...